# com.android.phone has stopped working after manually upgrading Verizon LG G3 (VS985) to Marshmallow using LGUP tool

Tags: stock-rom, verizon, lg-g3, telephony

I manually upgraded my LG VS985 to marshmallow from Kitkat using the LGUP tool and the LG Stock Rom for Verizon (LG VS985 Firmware VS98547A_01_0314_ARB01.kdz).

After booting it just keeps showing this popup "com.android.phone has stopped working" making the phone very unusable.

The network settings relating to mobile networks do not show up in the network settings page.

After wiping cached data even through recovery cache partition wipe, it still shows up.

Then I use Logcat on Android studio and I get the following error

```
01-09 23:23:39.302 5403-5403/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.android.phone, PID: 5403
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: wait_time (code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE carriers ADD COLUMN wait_time INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5246)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4838)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4778)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                                              Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: wait_time (code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE carriers ADD COLUMN wait_time INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:893)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:504)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:726)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1784)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1715)
                                                 at com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider$DatabaseHelper.onUpgrade(TelephonyProvider.java:1351)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:256)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
                                                 at com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider.onCreate(TelephonyProvider.java:2481)
                                                 at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                                                 at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5243)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4838) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4778) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: How do you installed? Do you wiped data or restored any system app of previos kitkat? (Maybe conflict between different android versions)

Comment: I used the the LG update tool (LGUP) to flash the stock rom for marshmallow. I have hardly been able to use the phone talkless of restoring system app.